# Power Generation from Gases

Tags: thermodynamics, power

Can a heated gas be used to drive a turbine?

I am **not** referring to steam heaters here. Why are already RTP gases e.g. argon or helium not heated and pressurised then used for power generation?

*RTP abbreviated room temperature and pressure.

Comment: Sorry, but what does RTP mean?

Comment: room temperature and pressure

Comment: OK, but I think your question involves engineering more than physics.

Comment: I think this forum would provide the best insight, especially in regards to the thermodynamics of the problem.

Comment: OK, then in that case see my answer

Comment: Storing the heated gas, while keeping it heated, is a major engineering issue.

Comment: There is a lot of engineering involved, though. At high temperatures, gas turbines (with air) may be easier to make than steam turbines (corrosion, erosion).

Comment: @JonCuster Sorry but I don't understand what "storing the heated gas" has to do with this. Can you please explain.

Comment: Is argon or helium too expensive for power generation?

Comment: it can be recycled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a heated gas be used to drive a turbine?

Yes.  In fact, in gas- and kerosene-powered turbines heated gas in the form of combustion products do exactly that.

> Why are already RTP gases e.g. argon or helium not heated and pressurised then used for power generation?

Because for any heat engine to work efficiently, the working fluid needs to be compressed, heated, and then expanded through some engine that captures the heat energy (i.e., a turbine).  It turns out that if you use a working fluid that is a gas at working temperatures but which condenses to a liquid as temperatures just below its working temperature range, then the compressing phase is very energy efficient -- the energy cost of compression is essentially equal to the pressure change times the fluid volume; on a mass per mass basis, compressing an already-condensed liquid is much more energy efficient.

This is why most heat engines that use an external heat source (i.e., coal or nuclear power plants*) use steam turbines rather than compressed (and heated) air turbines.

Google "Rankine cycle" for more information.

* Not to mention combined cycle power plants, that have a gas turbine (Brayton cycle) followed by a steam turbine (Rankine cycle) that recovers heat energy from the hot exhaust gasses of the gas turbine.

Answer (score 3):

> Can a heated gas be used to drive a turbine?

Yes. I think the thermodynamics of the problem is fairly straight forward. The work done by the gas turbine is the difference between the entering and exiting enthalpies of the gas.

Hope this helps.